# Merging Database State with Data added on Runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have written a little ToDo list App with Database interaction in React/ Redux to get an idea how these technologies works.

Current State:

On componentDidMount() I dispatch and Ajax Call and display the items from Database in a List. The User is able to add new Items to the Database, BUT I´m not able to append it to the existing rendered list.
Here is my Code.

My Child Component where the list is rendered:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


 export default class TodoList extends Component {

  render() {
  const posts = this.props.todos
  console.log(this.props.items)
  const items = this.props.items
  const isEmpty = posts.length === 0
   return (

    <div>
        <h3>Meine Aufgaben</h3>
        <ul>
           { this.props.items.items && this.props.items.items.length &&
                this.props.items.items.map((item, i) => <li key={i}>{item}</li>)}</li>)}
        </ul>
        <ul>

            {isEmpty
                ? <h3>Sie haben noch keinen Todo´s angelegt</h3>
                : <h3>Ihre Ergebnisse</h3>
            }
            {this.props.todos.map((todo, i) => <li key={i}>{todo.text}</li>)}
        </ul>
    </div>
    )
   }
  }
  const mapStateToProp = state => ({todos: state.addItem, items: state.getItem})

export default connect (mapStateToProp)(TodoList)
```

The Actions for fetching from Database:

```
export default function getItems(){
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch (fecthItem())
 }
}

function fecthItem(){
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestPost())
    return fetch('http://localhost:444/localWebServices/getCounter.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(json)))
   }
}

function requestPost(){
console.log("requesting posts");
return {
    type: 'REQUEST_POST'
 }
}

function receivePosts(json){
console.log("receivePosts");
var items = [];
for (var i = 0, len = json.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(json[i].text);
    items.push(json[i].text)
}
console.log(items);
return {
    type: 'RECEIVE_POSTS',
    items: items
 }
}
```

And the Reducer:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
switch (action.type){
    case 'RECEIVE_POSTS':
        console.log(action.items)
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            items: action.items
        });
    default:
        return state
   }
 }
```

This code works. But now I want to enable the user to add new Items to the list. The Code for adding Items to the Database also works, but I don´t understand how to append the new Item to the exist list, because I have saved them in different states. But how can I merge that?

The actions for adding Items:

```
let nextTodoId = 0

export default function addItem(item){
console.log("test")
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch (postItem(dispatch, item))
   } 
 }

function postItem(dispatch, item){
return dispatch => {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:444/localWebServices/addTask.php",
        data: {text: item}
    }).success(function(data){
        console.log("SUCCESS")
        dispatch(receiveAdd(item))
    });
   }
 }

function receiveAdd(item){
console.log("receive add")
return {
    type: 'ADD_ITEM',
    id: nextTodoId++,
    item
   }
 }
```

And the reducer:

```
 export default (state = [], action) => {
 switch (action.type){
     case 'ADD_ITEM':
        //return action.item
        return [
            ...state,
            {
                id: action.id,
                text: action.item
            }
        ]
    default:
        return state

   }
}
```

I have currently excluded the List to display the new Items from the child component, anyway this is irrelevant for this Question.

So how can I append the new added Items to the existing Initial-State and append it to the rendered list in my Child Component.

Any help would save my day :)

UPADTE:

Store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index'

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, createLogger())
)

if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
        const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers').default
        store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer)
})
}

return store
}
```

And my Index Reducer

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import addItem from './addItem'
import getItem from './getItem'
import todos from './todos'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  addItem,
  getItem
})

export default rootReducer
```

And here is my Container Component, where the addItem function is dispatched:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import AddTodo from '../components/AddTodo'
import TodoList from '../components/TodoList'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import addItem from '../actions/addItem'
import getItems from '../actions/getItems'

class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.state = {text: ''}
}

handleClick(e){
    console.log(e);
    const {dispatch} = this.props
    dispatch(addItem(e));
}

componentDidMount(){
    console.log("COMPONENT MOUNT");
    const {dispatch} = this.props
    dispatch(getItems())
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("GETTT IT");
    console.log(nextProps)
}

render() {

    return (
        <div>
        < h1 > Hallo </h1>
            <AddTodo handleAddItem={this.handleClick}/>
            <TodoList/>
        </div>
    )
   }
 }

App.propTypes = {
 dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
 return {
    AddTodo,
    TodoList
 }
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps)(App)
```

UPDATE 2:

And Here is a screenshot of my Dev-Console, after I added a new Item:

[image: Chrome Dev-Console]

[image: Chrome Dev-Console 2]

Comment: Does `localWebServices/addTask.php` response is an array of items, or the single added item? Because you treat it as an array in your reducer, and it might be a mistake. Furthermore, you use `connect` with `state.addItem` which I guess is the result of the `ADD_ITEM` reducer, but you treat `this.props.todos` as an array, and it's actually an object that holds an `items` fields which might be an array.

Comment: I have updated my ADD_ITEM Code, cause I posted some wrong code. Currently the addTask.php does return nothing, but in future it should return the created ID.

Comment: OK, it does seem better now, can you please add your reducer configuration?

Comment: Reducer seems fine too. We're gonna get it eventually! Can you please show me where do you call the `addItem(item)` function?

Comment: I see that you use the `redux-logger` middleware. It will help you determine if the issue is in you redux login (actions/reducers etc) or on the presentation layer (meaning the react component). Can you please check your developer tools to make sure the action is being dispatched as expected and that the state is updated?

Comment: Can you please add another screenshot with the `addItem` expanded in the "next state" line?

Comment: Yep, I have also append that

Comment: OK, so now we know the logic works. The issue is probably in the `TodoList` component. Can you maybe add a `console.log` to the `this.props.todos`?

Comment: In the render()? http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160608/q6zssftj.png

Comment: It seems perfectly fine! Are you sure this is not working as expected?

Comment: Probably you haven´t correctly understand my Question. The added Item is added to a list, but to the todo list (the second one). But I want to append the new item to the existing list (the first one in this.props.items.items) Currently it can´t correctly work, because i render two different list and don´t now how to put the item from todos in the items prop. :)

Comment: OK, that was a misunderstanding! Please see my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114100/discussion-between-gilad-artzi-and-baylife).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually do not need to use `combineReducers`. You simply need to unify both your reducers into a single reducer, that will look like:

```
export default (state = { items: [] }, action) => {
switch (action.type){
    case 'RECEIVE_POSTS':
        console.log(action.items)
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            items: action.items
        });
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            items: [
                ...items,
                action.item
            ]
        });
    default:
        return state
    }
}
```

This way you have a single array of todo items. Don't forget to change the `connect` call if you drop the `combineReducers` - `state => ({todos: state.addItem, items: state.getItem})` will simply be `state => (items: state.items})`

Comment: Hm, currently it isn´t working. I have excluded the combineReduer. In my store I have included the file with the code from your answer, and put it imported file in my CreateStore function. Then in my render Component, i have included the new state (connect). But this results in "Cannot read property 'items' of undefined"

Comment: We must figure out where the exception occurs. Are you able to create a https://plnkr.co/ or something with the updated code?

Comment: I'd rather not set up the environment on my local machine. Can you please try to figure out where does the "Cannot read property..." exception comes from?

Comment: would you join the chat?